# WePay payment gateway integration in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

I would like to implement Wepay into my Application, as of in-App-purchase, I have searched i could not find any Links regarding Integration, I even could not find any SDK's.

I am thinking of implementing this using any of the Web-Services, but i am not clear how to approach that, Can any Person Having idea on this Can You guide me to Achieve this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to sell features of the app you will have to use IAP (read the iOS guidelines).** If you are going to sell real products or services which are independent to your app (like web services) you aren't not allowed to use IAP and you must use something like WePay.

If you want to sell real products or web services setup a web based shop which uses WePay (with the PHP SDK) and let the app just interact with your web shop.

Another approach would be implementing it directly inside the app. I would strongly advise against implementing the payment process directly inside the app. This would be stupidly easy to hack since your customers can change the binary of your app.

Comment: Mihohl: Hi, Thank you for the answer and advice, as you advised me to use PHP SDK, May i know the procedure to integrate this..

Comment: For the PHP SDK should be enough information available here: https://github.com/wepay/php-sdk

Comment: For information about how to send HTTP requests from your app to your server I would have a look at the http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/products/ios-framework-introducing-mknetworkkit/ - He described everything very well in his blog.

Answer (score 0):

As an update, you can integrate WePay via the iOS SDK.

https://www.wepay.com/developer/resources/ios